# Get titles from playlist videos in YouTube iframe API (javascript)

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, youtube

I know that you can usually get current video titles using:

```
player.getVideoData().title;
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to get the titles from the playlist rather than just the current video and WITHOUT using the YouTube Data API? There is:

```
player.getPlaylist();
```

But it only returns an array of video IDs. Is this even possible, or must I go through the YouTube Data API?